# MAUI Android Binding not able to find static method switchMap

Tags: maui, maui-android

I have an Android Java Library Binding project to wrap a 3rd party proprietary aar file.  I have references to all of the gradle dependencies from Nuget.

When I include this in my MAUI project and invoke a method in the 3rd party library, it fails with a Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError for

```
No static method switchMap(Landroidx/lifecycle/LiveData;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;)Landroidx/lifecycle/LiveData; in class Landroidx/lifecycle/Transformations; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.lifecycle.Transformations' appears in /data/app/~~nc148mxJP3ubB6LuE_y2sQ==/redactedprojectname-6PoxTqeNItnSDp6kd3XKQw==/base.apk)
```

The included libraries are

```
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Room.Runtime" Version="2.5.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.Ktx" Version="2.6.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.WebKit" Version="1.6.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout" Version="2.1.4.4" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference" Version="1.2.0.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView" Version="1.3.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout" Version="1.1.0.12" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat" Version="1.6.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material" Version="1.7.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.Ktx" Version="2.6.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core" Version="2.6.1.1" />
```